# Android Installation on Windows

Tags: android, windows

I download

> android-sdk_r06-windows_2
>
> eclipse-java-helios-win32
>
> ADT-0.9.7
>
> jdk-6u21-windows-i586
>
> apache-ant-1.8.1-bin

and i follow google guide but i can't install android because
when i want to run android sdk below error occur

> Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: dl-ssl.google.com

when i want to run eclipse below error occur

> JDK need

but i installed jdk before

How can i install it ?
Do i need other files accept these files?

Comment: should be moved to superuser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

When you see the message `Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml`, close that window, go to Settings (on the left) and check `Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...`.

Comment: Yes. I always have to do this.

Comment: i change https to http but again occur error
i live in country that google dowsn't allow download from its site without prtoxy is it important ?